# How to delete an item in the listview using onItemLongClick?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-alertdialog, onlongclicklistener

I already created an `onItemLongClick` that will display the following `alertdialog` when `listview` is long clicked. The problem with my code is that even if I selected "Edit" as an option from the list, the item will still be deleted.

I wanted to put an intent when I click "Edit" and delete the item when I click "Delete" and I have no clue on how to create a conditional statement to do that.

[image]

Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
<-- start of snippet -->

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> View view, final int position, long id){
   Persons selectedPersons = this.list.get(position);
   String name = selectedPersons.getName();

   final CharSequence[] options = {"Edit", "Delete"};

   builder.Items(options, new DialogInterference.OnClickListener(){

      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
          list.remove(position);
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Item deleted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
});
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();

return true;

}

<-- end of snippet -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an if condition inside your onClick like this -

```
@Override
 public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> View view, f final int position, long id){
    Persons selectedPersons = this.list.get(position);
    String name = selectedPersons.getName();

    final CharSequence[] options = {"Edit", "Delete"};

   builder.Items(options, new DialogInterference.OnClickListener(){

      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
          if(options[which].equals("Delete") {
              list.remove(position);
              adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Item deleted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           } else if(options[which].equals("Edit") {
                 //Do edit
           }

      }
});
```

Comment: Yes it worked, I just don't know how to put a condition to get the value of edit and delete. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add a alertdialog onItemLongClick() event of the list.
Some thing like this:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Are you sure?")
    .setMessage("Do you want to delete this MemberClass?")
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        list.remove(position);
        Toast.makeText(DeleteMember.this, "Deleted Member", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }})
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null).show();
}
```